# Map through two arrays of components and strings and render in one component

Tags: reactjs

I have two arrays that I want to map through:

`const social = ["Snapchat", "TikTok", "Dribbble", "Discord", "Facebook"];`

`const socialIcons = [<SnapchatIcon />, <DribbbleIcon />];`

The `socialIcons` array are all components

How can I send both values as props into my `DummyRectangle` component? Here is my current code:

```js
  {social.map((s, index) => (
                  <div className="dummy_buttonsWrapper">
                    <DummRectangle social={s} socialIcons={i} />
                  </div>
                ))}
```

And here is `DummyRectangle` component:

```js
function DummRectangle({ social, socialIcons }) {
  // console.log("---->", socialIcons);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{social}</p>
      {<socialIcon/>} // render social icon component
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Some console logs or errors would be nice if you provide them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, you don't need to wrap tags around your `socialIcon` in your `DummRectangle`. Also, it doesn't seem that you are passing the `socialIcon` component at all. If I were you, I would do something like this:

The following two are the components as an example that you would like to render (in your case - `socialIcons`)

```js
// Comp1.js
import React from "react";

const Comp1 = () => <div>actual Comp1</div>;

export default Comp1;
```

```js
// Comp2.js
import React from "react";

const Comp2 = () => <div>actual Comp2</div>;

export default Comp2;
```

Now, in your main Parent component, you would simply get the current component of the `componentName` (in your case - `social`) by accessing your component's array with an index. Then, you would pass this `currentComponent` as props to your Child component where you want to render it.

```js
// App.js
import React from "react";

import Comp1 from "./Comp1";
import Comp2 from "./Comp2";
import DummyComponent from "./DummyComponent";

export default function App() {
  const componentNames = ["Comp1", "Comp2"];
  const components = [<Comp1 />, <Comp2 />];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {componentNames.map((name, index) => {
        const currentComponent = components[index];

        return (
          <div>
            <DummyComponent componentName={name} component={currentComponent} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your Child component, you can simply render it by enclosing it into the brackets - no need to add tags. React will do all the rendering for you. In your case it would be `{ socialIcon }`

```js
// DummyComponent.js
import React from "react";

const DummyComponent = ({ componentName, component }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{componentName}</p>
      {component}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DummyComponent;
```

Link to Codesandbox with the above code for reference: [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-paper-2yncz?file=/src/DummyComponent.js:0-206)